# How can I rewrite this to remove select statement joins?

Tags: mysql

As it is now each time I am selecting from Bill in my actual database I am searching over 1 million rows. There has to be a better way to write this query, but I haven't been able to figure it out. There has to be some way I can write this that doesn't join using the select statements.

If you notice I have some form of this join three seperate times. What should I do to remove this join?

```
    join
    ( 
    select b.year
         , sum(bli.amount) amt 
      from Bill b 
      join BillLine bli 
        on bli.bill_id = b.id 
     where bli.payment = 0 
       and bli.refund = 0 
       and bli.type = 3 
     group 
        by b.year
     ) org 
      on org.year = b.year
```

```
select  b.Year, 
        Round(case when b.year = (select collectoryear -1 from Entity) then 0 else beg.amt end,2) Beginning,
        Round(case when b.year >= (select collectoryear -1 from Entity) then ifnull(org.amt,0) else 0 end,2) Additions, 
        Round(case when b.year = (select collectoryear -1 from Entity) then 0 else beg.amt end + case when b.year >= (select collectoryear -1 from Entity) then ifnull(org.amt,0) else 0 end - ending.amt ,2) Collections,
                Round(ending.amt,2) Ending
from Bill b 
    left join Levy l on l.year = b.year 
    join Entity e on b.year = e.year
    join( select b.year, sum(bli.amount) amt from Bill b join BillLine bli on bli.bill_id = b.id where bli.payment = 0 and bli.refund = 0 and bli.type = 3 group by b.year) org on org.year = b.year
    join( select b.year, sum(bli.amount) amt from Bill b join BillLine bli on bli.bill_id = b.id where bli.type = 2 group by b.year ) beg on beg.year = b.year
    join( select b.year, sum(bli.amount) amt from Bill b join BillLine bli on bli.bill_id = b.id where bli.type = 2 group by b.year ) ending on ending.year = b.year
where b.year > (select collectoryear -11 from Entity) 
and b.year < (select collectoryear from Entity) 
group by b.year
order by Year desc ;
```

Here is the db-fiddle databases

```
create table Bill 
( id varchar(20) PRIMARY KEY
, year varchar(20) FOREIGN KEY
);

Insert into Bill (id, year) values 
(1, 2020), 
(2, 2020), 
(3, 2020), 
(4, 2019), 
(5, 2019), 
(6, 2018), 
(7, 2017), 
(8, 2016), 
(9, 2015), 
(10, 2013);

create table BillLine 
( id varchar(20) PRIMARY KEY
, bill_id varchar(20) FOREIGN KEY
, amount varchar(20)
, refund varchar(20)
, payment varchar(20)
, type varchar(20)
);

Insert into BillLine (id, bill_id, amount, refund, payment, type) values 
(1, 10, 100.00, 0, 0, 3), 
(2, 9, 250.00, 1, 1, 5), 
(3, 8, 102.00, 0, 0, 3), 
(4, 7, 85.00, 1, 1, 5), 
(5, 6, 20.00, 0, 0, 3), 
(6, 5, 43.75, 0, 1, 2), 
(7, 4, 22.22, 0, 0, 3), 
(8, 3, 125.25, 0, 1, 2), 
(9, 2, 77.70, 0, 0, 3), 
(10, 1, 100.75, 1, 1, 5);               

create table Entity 
( id varchar(20) PRIMARY KEY
, collectoryear varchar(20)
, year varchar(20)
);

Insert into Entity (id, collectoryear, year) values (1, 2021, 2020);

create table Levy 
( id varchar(20) PRIMARY KEY, county varchar(20), year varchar(20) 
);

Insert into Levy (id, county, year) values (1, null, null);
```

Comment: I'm not sure that I understand why using a GROUP BY clause there is not appropriate. If I don't use it I get multiples in my results. Is there a better option? Like DISTINCT or something?

Comment: I re-edited it. It actually has an id as its Primary Key. Sorry for the confusion.

Comment: I've made my question more specific. Hopefully that will help.